# ReactJS version is <1. is it production-ready (main API immutable on version bump)?

Tags: reactjs, production-environment, semantic-versioning

As the title said,

I was considering using React in a production-ready project (in particular: Meteor's **Material-ui** module).

As it's not even at `v1.0` then is it stable enough to use in production? What downsides are there to using a <`1.0` version?

Comment: Depends what you call production ready https://twitter.com/matzatorski/status/633540204247261185

Comment: Looks like Facebook has been using it in production for over [two years](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html)...

Comment: You could have asked the same question about node until a few weeks ago!

Comment: @Clarkie, hat do you mean?

Comment: @dragonmnl [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) just went from `v0.12` to `v4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you or the organisation you work for are a devoted follower of the [semver](http://semver.org/) method of versioning then it would be very risky to use anything that is less than `v1.0` due to the following clause:

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

All this means is that that a library changing from `0.x` to `0.y` (including `0.x` to `1`) may have a completely different api which could mean you need to do a lot of work to upgrade.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wonder if this is this a "general rule"? The twitted @knowbody mentioned would prove the contrary. Also I see dev-preview nowhere for React

Comment: It entirely depends on your project. It's always a trade off between 'stability' and 'features'. If you're using the latest version of a lib then expect to come across issues. (But that's part of the fun!)